# Adding Pop-up Message in Django

Tags: javascript, django, web, popup, message

i want to display popup message like (welcome <user>) when user will log in.
i can add this message to a section of the page by using Django messages 
 **Like** `messages.success(request,welcome {request.user}')`
 and **in template** 
`{% if messages %}` 
`<ul class="messages">` 
`{% for message in messages %}` 
`<li class="{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</li>`
`{% endfor %}`

`</ul>`

`{% endif %}` 
but i don't want that.
i just want a popup message for few seconds 
How can i do that in a Django project?
 Or, is there any way of doing that by using java script event listener? 
 Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li id="message_container" class="{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</li>

<script>
var message_ele = document.getElementById("message_container");

setTimeout(function(){ 
message_ele.style.display = "none"; 
}, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, That's worked, can you please tell me that how to use this message only for first time when user log in?

Comment: which case it is?

Comment: Like when user login to see dashboard,I used user code but problem is every time I'm accessing the dashboard it showing welcome every time, but i am wondering that user will see the welcome message only for first time when they will login and access the dashboard page.

Answer (score 0):

When user will log in, you will have access to User object in and you can pass it to the view in the "context", which I am sure you are already doing. Then you can show an alert with the message or if you want something fancy you can use a Bootstrap modal.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

```
{% if user %}
alert('Hello', '{{user.name}}'
{% endif %}
```

If you want to use Django messages:

```
{% if messages %}
alert('{{message}}')
{% endif %}
```